# How to select a node and start renaming in a SWT tree?

Tags: swt, jface

How to select a node and start renaming in a `SWT` `Tree`? After single mouse click on the node only I am able to use <kbd>F2</kbd>. My usecase is - immediately after adding a new Tree node I should be able to press <kbd>F2</kbd> and start renaming. But just setting focus and  selection on the tree does not select the node explicitly. Is there any other code?

```
treeViewer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(newNode), true);
treeViewer.getTree().setFocus();
```

This does not seem to work.

Comment: F2 is not built in editing trigger for SWT Trees, so you can't expect this to work out of the box. Unless the tree viewer comes from e.g. Project Explorer view.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is `newNode`? It should be an element from your content provider.

Also, a lot of people have been having trouble with this limitation of the **SWT/JFace** toolkits. See [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=198260) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852574/swt-table-how-to-set-get-focused-row).