# how to catch event of change focus of row in tableViewer?

Tags: java

I created a tableViewer.
The tableViewer could be update.

The update of the table is in inline mode meaning in change of row Ii will update the table.

The problem that if I changed the focus to different view  ( outline , tasks... ) or to different windows I want to catch the event that the focus of the table was changed.( the row still mark and this is the reason that the selectionChanegd event is not trigger )

This is the event that for the selectionChanged

```
 gridController.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
         .. do update
```

}

The event is not trigger when I changed the focus to different window,view.

Do you know on different way to catch the change of the focus of the table ?

Comment: Could you please clarify, what have you done, more than that one row? Also tag the question properly.

Comment: Have you tried e.g. FocusListener, that has FocusLost event? Without code though, cannot say that is the problem solved with changing approach or debugging the existing code..

Comment: Check out this link it may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852574/swt-table-how-to-set-get-focused-row

Comment: provide some more code and elaborate your question

Comment: I tried event foucs and it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ArrayContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelectionChangedListener;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.LabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.SelectionChangedEvent;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class TestCase {

private static List<String> model = new ArrayList<String>();
private static TableViewer viewer;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

//  viewer = new TableViewer(shell, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.FULL_SELECTION |    SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.VIRTUAL);
    viewer = new TableViewer(shell, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.VIRTUAL);

    viewer.getTable().setHeaderVisible(true);
    viewer.getTable().setLinesVisible(true);
    viewer.setUseHashlookup(true);

    viewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
    viewer.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider());

    model.add("element2");
    model.add("element1");
    model.add("element0");

    viewer.setInput(model);

    viewer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(model.get(1)));

    viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
            System.out.println("selection changed");
        }
    });

    addContent();

    shell.setSize(400, 400);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}

private static void addContent() {
    Display.getCurrent().timerExec(2000, new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            model.add(0, "element" + model.size());
            viewer.refresh();
            addContent();
        }
    });
}

}
```